# Landsat 8 Collection 2 cloud-free mosaics in Earth Engine

Tags: python, google-earth-engine, landsat, landsat-8, cloudmasking

I am trying to get cloud-free mosaics from 6-months periods of [Landsat 8 Collection 2 Surface Reflectance](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/datasets/catalog/LANDSAT_LC08_C02_T1_L2#bands).

So far I've used geetools. My code consists of multiple modules so I can't paste it all here, but the relevant part looks like this:

```
def get_cloudfree_coll(start_date, end_date, clip_geometry, aoi, max_cloud):

    collection = (ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LC08/C02/T1_L2')
        .filterBounds(aoi)
        .filterDate(start_date, end_date))\
        .filter(ee.Filter.lt('CLOUD_COVER', int(max_cloud)))\
        .map(lambda image: image.clipToCollection(clip_geometry))

    collection = collection.select(['SR_B1', 'SR_B2' ,'SR_B3', 'SR_B4', 'SR_B5', 'QA_PIXEL'],['B1', 'B2', 'B3', 'B4', 'B5', 'pixel_qa'])
    clean_coll = collection.map(clean)

    return clean_coll


def clean(image):
    
    mask = geetools.cloud_mask.landsatSR(['cloud', 'shadow', 'adjacent'])

    return mask(image)


collection = processor.get_cloudfree_coll(START_DATE, END_DATE, locations_ee, AOI, max_cloud=50)
median = (collection.select(['B2', 'B3', 'B4', 'B5'])
                                    .median())
```

I clip the images to a FeatureCollection which is a set of squares of size 1x1km. An example of what the results look like:

[image]

Clearly, there are some cloud-related artefacts still visible. I can just disregard squares with missing data so the data gaps are not so much a problem. But I would optimally need the data to not show any signs of clouds.

In addition to the code above, I've looked at [EE Landsat Algorithms page](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/guides/landsat) where they describe a workflow to get "Simple composite"of the least cloudy pixels, however they talk about **TOA (Top Of Atmosphere)** whereas I need **Surface Reflectance**.

Also, there are many questions on this topic but I find that they are mostly about Collection 1 which has been now deprecated and Collection 2 may be different.

**Question:** How to improve cloud masking to get rid of the visible cloud artifacts shown on the screenshot?